# Trying to create multiple .xlsx files with conditional formatting in R

Tags: r, excel, conditional-formatting, openxlsx

I’m wondering if there is a way to do the following in R:

1. Produce separate .xlsx workbooks from a single dataset based on a column value
2. Apply conditional formatting to rows in each .xlsx file based on a column value

I can do each of these separately, but efforts to combine them haven't been successful and I can't find an exact use-case match online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can't share my specific data, but here is a sample that replicates the data I have.

```
df <- data.frame (
  assign = c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "YES", "YES", "NO"),
  dept = c("HIST","HIST", "PSYC", "PSYC", "PSYC", "ENGL", "ENGL", "ENGL"),
  class = c(1009, 1330, 1001, 1015, 2190, 1001, 3001, 4390))
```

I can successfully create separate workbooks by generating a list of the dept variable and then using lapply(), but attempts to incorporate conditional formatting are unsuccessful:

```
# create a list of dept values to split into separate workbooks
li <- split(df, with(df, df$dept), drop = FALSE)

# using lapply to generate .xlsx docs
lapply(names(li), function(x){write.xlsx(li[[x]], "report", file = paste0("report_", x, ".xlsx"), row.names = FALSE)})
```

With the following code, I can generate a .xlsx file with conditional formatting, but can only produce a single file with all rows rather than multiple files:

```
# create style for classes that haven’t finished the assignment
noadmin <- createStyle(fontColour = "#FF0000", fontSize = 10)

# create style for top row
Heading <- createStyle(textDecoration = "bold", fgFill = "#FFFFCC", border = "TopBottomLeftRight")

# workbook call begins here
assign_all <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(assign_all, 1, gridLines = TRUE)
writeData(assign_all, 1, df, withFilter = TRUE)

# identify which rows didn’t complete (e.g., need to be formatted)
noRows = data.frame(which(df$assign == "NO", arr.ind=FALSE))

# freeze top row
freezePane(assign_all, 1, firstActiveRow = 2, firstActiveCol = 1)

# add style to header
addStyle(assign_all, 1, cols = 1:ncol(df), rows = 1, style = Heading)

# add style to "NO" rows
addStyle(assign_all, 1, cols = 1:ncol(df), rows = noRows[,1]+1, style = noadmin, gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(assign_all, paste0("report.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

This produces the output I want, but with all rows in one file:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide. I've been working on this problem for a few weeks and have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your code to create the workbook inside a function, then loop over the list of splitted dataframes to create your xlsx files. Instead of `lapply` I use `mapply` to loop over both the list and the names:

```r
li <- split(df, df$dept)

library(openxlsx)
# create style for classes that haven’t finished the assignment
noadmin <- createStyle(fontColour = "#FF0000", fontSize = 10)

# create style for top row
Heading <- createStyle(textDecoration = "bold", fgFill = "#FFFFCC", border = "TopBottomLeftRight")

make_xl <- function(x, y) {
  assign_all <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(assign_all, 1, gridLines = TRUE)
  writeData(assign_all, 1, x, withFilter = TRUE)
  
  # identify which rows didn’t complete (e.g., need to be formatted)
  noRows = data.frame(which(x$assign == "NO", arr.ind=FALSE))
  
  # freeze top row
  freezePane(assign_all, 1, firstActiveRow = 2, firstActiveCol = 1)
  
  # add style to header
  addStyle(assign_all, 1, cols = 1:ncol(x), rows = 1, style = Heading)
  
  # add style to "NO" rows
  addStyle(assign_all, 1, cols = 1:ncol(x), rows = noRows[,1]+1, style = noadmin, gridExpand = TRUE)
  
  saveWorkbook(assign_all, paste0("report_", y, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)  
}

mapply(make_xl, li, names(li))
#> ENGL HIST PSYC 
#>    1    1    1

list.files(pattern = "^report")
#> [1] "report_ENGL.xlsx" "report_HIST.xlsx" "report_PSYC.xlsx"
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! This is exactly what I was looking for. You are a rock star, stefan. I really appreciate your help.